# Docker creates additional bridge in wrong IP range

Tags: networking, docker, docker-networking

I followed the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range) and changed the daemon.json to:

```
{
  "bip": "10.200.0.1/24",
  "default-address-pools": [
      { "base":"10.201.0.0/16","size":24 },
      { "base":"10.202.0.0/16","size":24 }
  ]
}
```

as I wanted to change the IP range used by the docker networking. However, when I start there is still a bridge created belonging to the IP range I wanted to move away from:

```
8: br-6c870af107ba: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:ef:44:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-6c870af107ba
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I prevent docker from creating this bridge interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently docker has a restart resistant cashed config. You need to run `docker network prune`. Now the bridge is not created anymore and I successfully moved my IP range.