# How to forward WSL2 8080 to Windows host's 8080?

Tags: iptables, docker, port-forwarding, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have:

1. a Spring Boot **application running** on Windows **on 8080** and
2. a **service** running **in the Docker container within the WSL2** Ubuntu, and

I'm loking how to *enable the Windows host's 8080 to this service?*

The **limitation** is that the service is part of the development setup and is built with the docker-compose, so the solution should be IP-independent or fully (maximally) automated.

The application is reachable with `curl $(hostname).local:8080`, but when I try to add `iptables` rules (based on those [found here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)) to redirect *"wsl:8080->winhost:8080"*:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -o eth0 -p tcp --syn --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i lo -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o lo -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.28.80.1:8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -d 172.28.80.1 -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.1:8080
```

where `172.28.80.1` - is the Windows host IP, then `curl` starts hanging until timeout.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to connect from inside a container to the Windows host? If yes, use `host.docker.internal` as the hostname of the Windows host. You do not need to use `iptables`, etc.

Comment: `host.docker.internal` maps to the WSL (internal) localhost not to the Windows localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make connection from inside a Docker container under WSL2 to a port opened on the Windows machine (php container with xdebug on ubuntu connecting to phpstorm on windows) as follows:

1. map host in docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yml and rebuild container

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: debug
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

2. pinging `host.docker.internal` from container should now reveal the ip allocated by docker for it's network or you can manually specify the bridge ip and default docker subnet IP range(s) by creating a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following structure - more details here: https://serverfault.com/a/942176/1029877

```
{
  "bip": "172.30.0.1/16",
  "default-address-pools":[
    {"base":"172.32.0.0/16","size":24},
    {"base":"172.33.0.0/16","size":24},
    {"base":"172.34.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

where

- `bip` would be the value that docker maps under `host.docker.internal`
- `default-address-pools` will be used for allocating ip addresses to containers

3. then define a new iptable rule as follows

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -d 172.30.0.1 -p tcp --dport 9003 --to 172.24.96.1
```

where

- `172.30.0.1` is the destination of the initial request - where is trying to connect
- `172.24.96.1` is the ip address assigned to WSL network - where we need to forward the request
- `9003` is the port - the same for both source and destination

More resources for inspiration or issues that I've stumbled upon:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-reach-localhost-on-host-from-docker-container/113321/15 and https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/  -- didn't happen for me
- https://askubuntu.com/a/320125/1678663 and - https://askubuntu.com/questions/466445/what-is-masquerade-in-the-context-of-iptables -- I haven't used `MASQUERADE` and described solution works good enough for what I need
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881373/1091730 - looking to try the 3'rd solution to manually remap the assigned ipaddress to WSL instance by changing `IPAddress` key value under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{{wsl-network-id}}` in registry

Now I am looking to automate this and make sure it doesn't have any issues when changing network connections or after wakeup from sleep / hybernate (as it happens from time to time with another port forwarding over ssh -- however this might be related to some drivers on my device).